# How can I change the color of a dynamically generated linkbutton on mouse cursor focus with JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, button, events, client

Code:

```
LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton();
linkButton.OnClientClick="changecolor";--i need to change this to on mouse focus event
```

There is no property for link button like we have for `onClientClick`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
linkButton.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "yourChangeColorFunction();");
```

Comment: If you only want to change the color I would recommend using CSS as Jalpesh wrote, only the syntax is "a:hover { color: blue; }"

Answer (score 2):

You can define the CSS class for tha link button that will have different color when you hover.

```
a
{
  color:black;
}
a.hover
{
  color:blue;
}
```